# Wordpress hierarchy issue with categorized post not using specific template

Tags: wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming, categories, hierarchy

I'm trying to implement a dedicated template for any post with a category slug of 'rentals'. There are posts in the database with a category of rentals set up and applied. I've created the template with a standard loop and called it category-rentals.php, saving it in my root folder.

It's just not working. It keeps reverting to single post template (index.php specifically).

My rendered body classes are as such:
`post-template-default single single-post postid-278 single-format-standard`

Am I missing a step here?

category-rentals.php:

```
/*
* Rental property template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="background-image: url('<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/img/bg-semi-trans.png'), url('<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/img/bg-jumbotron.jpg');">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="headline text-center animated fadeInUp">
          <p><?php wp_title(''); ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

              <?php the_content(); ?>        

            <?php endwhile; else : ?>
              <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no content matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <hr>
            <a href="#">&larr; Go Back</a> | <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You have your [template hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/) mixed up. category-{slug} is when you are looking at an **archive page** of that given slug. Single posts use a different format which won't cover what you're looking for. You'll need to use an if condition to check for the current category on your single-post template, and use [get_template_part](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) to load in the correct markup.

Comment: Awesome! That makes total sense, I just misunderstood that. Thanks!